# Water is not transparent!

Tags: transparency

so i mixed glass bsdf and transparent bsdf but my water just won't turn transparent. I just don't understand what the problem is. I alreasy put roughness down and IOR to 1.333. I also have ocean modifier.
What is the problem?[image]

Comment: It does not show as transparent because you are not in _Rendered_ view mode. You have to set the _Blend Mode_ in the _Material Properties_ to something like _Alpha Hashed_ or _Alpha Blend_ to get transparency. And if you want to render in _Eevee_ this is necessary, too. Transparency only works with _Cycles_ by default without the need to change settings.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked! I changed from Eevee to Cycles and then it worked. I think that was the problem.